# Creating a node using Services 6.3 REST

Tags: nodes, 6, services

I am trying to create a node using the rest service. I am hitting `/myendpoint/node` using a post. My header is `application/json`. I am not sure what I need to post as the data.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this, &node[title]=testnode&node[type]=story&node[field_test][0][value]=testtting

Also, if you are ever unaware of what to send, just look at the tests.

Comment: `406 Not Acceptable: Missing required argument node`

Comment: look at which tests?

Comment: Kyle, what test were you referreing to in your answer and are there such tests for a D7 Services beginner to take advantage of?

Comment: The tests are in the test folder for the services module.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some ideas: https://gist.github.com/affc9864487bb1b9c918.

I assume you have `Content-Type: application/json` in your header.

Example curl call with session authentication:

```
curl -X POST "http://example.com/endpoint/node" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Cookie: {session_name}={session_id}" -d '{"type":"story","title":"Test Title","body":"Test Body"}'
```

Basically you have to post data in JSON format, that maps to the fields of the content type you want to create. If you have custom fields it is just a bit more tricky. See: http://drupal.org/node/1354202.