# How do I POST a new node?

Tags: services

I have referred many links including the following:

- [Services module. How to construct the JSON data with session info for creating node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/services-module-how-to-construct-the-json-data-with-session-info-for-creating-n)
- [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/kylebrowning/affc9864487bb1b9c918)
  - [Creating a node using Services 6.3 REST](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/creating-a-node-using-services-6-3-rest)

I tried several ways to POST a new node to a Drupal site, but I have failed. I have created a sample CCK for storing students data with name, age, gender, DOB, and added some list.

I have installed and configured the Services module (D7), and created a service end point at services.
As expected, GET is the easiest way to get details of a node in JSON. `http://localhost/drupal/services/node` simply listed all nodes.

I still can't figure out how to use the **POST** method.

1. I would like to search for the students whose name contains *john*. I tried `localhost/drupal/services/node&node[name]=john`. I used  **POST Man** plugin for Chrome without success. I also tried some other ways.
2. I tried adding a new student to the site without success.

Can anyone guide me to make the above work fine?

UPDATE :

I tried adding new nodes of type **article** . It worked fine. but when i am trying to add nodes of type **Department CCK** It is showing "**s:22:"CSRF validation failed";**" 
Here are the screen shots

I have gone through the link https://drupal.org/node/2013781

I followed session = session_name=session_id but i still get an error.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try to POST a node? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

For Drupal 7

Tools used:

- [Firefox Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) add-on to do tests and debugging. 
  There may be other add-on as well. But for this example im using Firefox add-on.
- To help editing and validating the JSON data you can use

  - Edit the JSON data using this [link](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/)
  - Validate the JSON data using this [link](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

**HTTP requests**

- To make the HTTP requests, you need use the Firefox add-on [POSTER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/).
- Two commonly used methods for a request-response between a client and server are:

  - GET
  - POST
- After the add-on is Downloaded. Open **Firefox -> Tools -> Poster**

  [image]
- Make sure to enable the **Session authentication**. After the **Services** is configured properly, before creating the node you should **log-in**. Once logged-in you can create the nodes.
- For login use POST method, with the URL like - http://XXXXXXXX.com/demo/rulebook/rulebook_endpoint/user/login

  [image]
- If it is a **valid user** then it will return **user details** with **session ID and Name**. If not valid it will return **Access denied**

  [image]
- By using Session name and ID in the POST HEADER, we can able to create new nodes

  [image]
- Now after adding the HEADER, You need to make HTTP POST request and make sure  user should have permissions to create node.

  [image]
- If the node is created you will get the response with node link

  [image]

NOTE : If you want the response in JSON then, you should always append .json at the end of the URL. eg., http://XXXXXXXX.com/test/endpoint/user.json OR http://XXXXXXXX.com/test/endpoint/node.json OR http://XXXXXXXX.com/test/endpoint/user/user_id.json OR http://XXXXXXXX.com/test/endpoint/node/node_id.json

Comment: Sorry i unchecked the form url-encoded option in services module. and here is the response 401: Unauthorised : CSRF authorisation failed. what might be causing this? Many thanks

Comment: hi @inizio may i know on what basis did you assigned session value in HEADERS. Can you make it clear. Example, the sessionId i got is SESS29af1facda0a866a687d5055f2fade2c but in your answer it has more length !

Comment: Session value in HEADERS consist of session_name and session_id.

ie., session is the variable and its value consist of session_name = session_id.

session = (session_name = session_value)

Comment: It says 401: Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed. I gave the following as headers name = session value =SESS29af1facda0a866a687d5055f2fade2c=gBVoqtkN2ZNjDyOjIfpz47oQpnmCKytcgHOCHZhKRzo

Comment: Yes it worked. But the only issue, The Article CCK has title,field_names, body but only title is being saved and node is  created, but body and names field are empty. How to overcome this.

Comment: You need to give proper format to create node. You can refer this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50559/services-module-how-to-construct-the-json-data-with-session-info-for-creating-n/77811#77811

Comment: I am unable to add new nodes for Custom created Content types. and also i am unable to provide correct session value. Please check my updated post. many thanks

Answer (score 8):

**For Drupal 7 and Services 7.x-3.x**

**Step 1:** Issue a post request to `user.login` resource with your username and password.

If the login is successful, you will get a response object with 4 properties:

- session_name
- sessid
- token
- user (object)

Screenshot from google chrome postman
[image: Screenshot from google chrome postman]

**Step 2:** Issue a post request to `node` with 2 headers

- Cookie: [session_name]=[sessid]
- X-CSRF-Token: [token]

Screenshot from google chrome postman
[image: Screenshot from google chrome postman]

Comment: I tried to user <endpoint>/user.login but its not repsonse: http://prntscr.com/gru4y6 -- not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you do *POST* to the *REST API* then you will have to put everything into *POST data*, not to *URL*. In *Postman* you can set the request to post, than type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and below that you can add your data values. Don't forget to add *status, uid, language, type, title* and then the extra values. The resource URL should be only `HOST/REST_API_PATH/node`.

Comment: Little confusing. Ok can you tell me what should be the parameters for creating a new article.? If you don't mind can you post an example or a link so that i can have a clear concept !